# Download files by links from .csv file

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I have .csv file which has two columns: name and http link:

```
name,link
IN0895,http://sample.com/images/example.jpg
IN0895,http://sample.com/images/example2.jpg
IN0872,http://sample.com/images/name.jpg
IN0872,http://sample.com/images/screen.jpg
```

I want create folder with name from first column and download file there (from second column). If folder already exists, just download file and put there.

How this can be done using bash, wget, curl or something else of your choice?

Answer (score 4):

Fields in CSV file are comma separated in your example.

filename for CSV file is given at commandline when you call the script.

modify script permissions.

test it in a temp folder first so you don't clutter and have to clean up if it doesn't work.

**not tested**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
filename="$1"
while IFS="," read f1 f2
do
  mkdir -p "$f1";
  wget -P "$f1" "$f2"
done < "$filename"
```

`mkdir -p` checks if directory exists and makes directory if it doesn't

`wget -P` is Prefix (Parent folder) for folder to download to in case you are downloading more than one thing from URL.

`f1` and `f2` are the 2 fields in CSV file. `f1` is the first field which will be the directory name and `f2` is the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something that does this in python. Keep in mind you have to install wget via `pip install wget` first.

```
import pandas as pd 
import wget

#read in data
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv") 

# assuming you have a column named Column1 which contains the link, iterate #through and download
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    link = wget.download(row['Column1'])
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  <?php
  // This is the class which is use for cURL operation..
  class curl_image {
      // Here two variable $name for Rename image, $img_url take image path
      function image($name,$img_url)
      {
         // Here we define a file path where download image will save...
         $path = "E:/xampp/htdocs/beauty_code_image/";

         // Now initialize curl instance here with related method
         $ch = curl_init($img_url);
         $fp = fopen($path . $name, 'wb');
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

         // cURL excute if above information is right otherwise show error msg
         $result = curl_exec($ch);

         // print_r($result);       it just for display cURL is executed or not
         curl_close($ch);       // Close cURL here
         fclose($fp);
      }
  }

   // Initialize class object here
   $obj = new curl_image();

   // Here we check file is exist
   if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']))
   {
        // We check here data is in valid mentioned format or not
        $csvMimes = array('application/vnd.msexcel','text/plain','text/csv','text/tsv');
        if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$csvMimes)){
            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){

                 //open uploaded csv file with read only mode
                 $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

                 // fetch csv file here using Php inbuild function                
                 fgetcsv($csvFile);  
                 while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){
                   // Here object fetch the method which download image & rename it with SKU name
                    $obj->image($line[0].'.jpg',$line[1]);
                  }
             }
             // Close CSV file
             fclose($csvFile);
        }
   }

    ?>

   <html>   
   <head></head>
   <body>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
      <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="importFrm">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="importSubmit" value="IMPORT">
               </form>
           </div>`enter code here`
       </div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some context around your source-code.
Code-only answers are difficult to understand.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Now this program have comments on wherever logic implements, it will help you, still you have any issue please tell me, by the way thanks for your attention...